# How can I remove duplicate points, And draw a diagram with X and Z axes in Halcon (MVTEC Software)?

Tags: image-processing, drawing, halcon

I am doing a project where I need to draw a laser line image on a graph. I got the coordinates of the laser points. I am going to draw a two-dimensional graph in the Halcon (MVTEC software) using points
Some points are duplicates and this prevents the diagram from being drawn correctly. How can I remove duplicate points? And draw a diagram with X and Z axes?
Please download the coordinate file via the link below:

https://s21.picofile.com/d/8445324542/15c1902a-0828-4692-b0ce-a65651306111/Coordinates.rar

Comment: Could you please provide the points?

Comment: Please download the coordinate file via the link below:

https://s21.picofile.com/d/8445324542/15c1902a-0828-4692-b0ce-a65651306111/Coordinates.rar

Answer (score 0):

There are actually no duplicate points in your dataset. The problem is that your data is essentially sorted by the wrong axis. You can re-sort and plot them like this:

```
read_tuple ('Rows.tup', Rows)
read_tuple ('Columns.tup', Cols)
* dev_inspect_ctrl (['plot_xy', Cols, Rows])

Indices := sort_index(Cols)
Rows2 := Rows[Indices]
Cols2 := Cols[Indices]

dev_get_window (WindowHandle)
plot_tuple (WindowHandle, Cols2, Rows2, [], [], [], [], [])
```